# HTML div grid scrollbar with fixed header row change the width of default rows

Tags: html, css, grid

I want to create a data grid without `table` using only `div` using html and css.
Doing this I am stuck on to making the header row  `fixed` and a scrollbar in main body of the grid.
So far I have done this

```css
.grid-body {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.grid-body-main {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.header-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #ddd;
}

.header-cell {
  width: 100%;
  border-right: solid thin #444;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.default-row {
  display: flex;
}

.default-cell {
  width: 100%;
  border-right: dotted thin #444;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  min-width: 150px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-body">
  <div class="header-row">
    <div class="header-cell">
      ID
    </div>
    <div class="header-cell">
      Name
    </div>
    <div class="header-cell">
      Username
    </div>
    <div class="header-cell">
      Email
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-body-main">

    <div class="default-row">
      <div class="default-cell">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        Aman
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        amansinghgusain
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        amansinghgusain@gmail.com
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="default-row">
      <div class="default-cell">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        Jon Doe
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        jondoe
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        jondoe@gmail.com
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="default-row">
      <div class="default-cell">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        Jon Doe
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        jondoe
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        jondoe@gmail.com
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="default-row">
      <div class="default-cell">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        Jon Doe
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        jondoe
      </div>
      <div class="default-cell">
        jondoe@gmail.com
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

> When vertical scrollbar appears, it covers a certain width which in
>   turn gets deducted from `grid-body-main` which creates difference in
>   `header row` and `body row` as clearly visible in this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jtjWCEOkOJU6tCyQcRG7?p=preview).

**Workaround**

> I want my grid to look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy4JE/), but not using `table`

Any help regarding this would be appreciable.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to do this in divs? Table would be the correct tag to use in this situation when displaying 'tabulated' data

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf Yes I have been told to do this using div's only, just for study purpose.